# How to fix a bug after stripe paymant

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have a website with games. I also included stripe as a payment method, and everything works pretty fine! But, after you finish your payment, you get redirected to your home page, and objects that are looped just DISSAPPEAR! They appear again once you travel from one page to another.

**Views.py**

```
def button_to_buy(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=[
            'card',
        ],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price': '',
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success'))
    )
    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)


def success_url(request):
    user = request.user.pk
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user)
    profile.subscription = True
    profile.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Оплата прошла успешно')
    return render(request, 'store/index.html')
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('checkout/', button_to_buy, name='checkout'),
path('success/', success_url, name='success'),
```

**Profile.html**

```
<div class="justify-content-center py-4 px-2">
          {% if not profile.subscription %}
              <form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button class="btn text-light bg-danger mt-4">Buy subscription</button>
              </form>
          {% else %}
              <button class="btn text-light bg-success mt-4">Already paid</button>
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "objects that are looped just DISSAPPEAR"? I don't see anything related to "objects" or "loop" in the code you shared.